# How functional programming can be better here (Java 8)

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

```
public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2,4,3,-5,-7);

        Collections.sort(list);

        int i = 0;
        int j = list.size()-1;

        int min = 1000;

        while (true) {
             int sum = list.get(i)+list.get(j);

             if (mod(sum) < min) {
                 min = mod(sum);
             }
             if (sum < 0) {
                 i++;
             }
             else if (sum ==0 ) {
                 i++;
                 j--;
             }
             else {
                 j--;
             }

             if (j <= i) {
                 break;
             }
        }

        System.out.println(min);

    }
    private static int mod(int sum) {
        return sum < 0 ? -sum : sum;
    }
}
```

Above code is to find sum nearest to zero by adding any two element. But I am unable to figure out how (without using loop) stream is going to help in writing more cleaner, readable code. What i have seen if inside for loop if there is not much logic, then use of stream makes code cleaner.

Comment: Lets see if someone comes by to solve that problem using streams. But you know - who says that **all** problems can be "better" using streams? I find them helpful sometimes, but not all the times. The **only** real thing with streams: when you got a stream solution, you can *try* to go parallel just by changing to use parallelStream(). Try doing that with your solution ...

Comment: you are moving up and down the list with two indices (i and j) - I doubt you can find an elegant stream solution to do the same thing. Unless you change the algorithm. Also note that your `mod` method should probably be called `abs` - and you don't really need it: `Math.abs(sum)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You could stream the list and `flatMap` it against the same list streamed again, and then use the stream's `min` method.
The code would definitely be shorter, but whether or not it would be easier to read is in the eye of the beholder:

```
int min = list.stream()
              .flatMapToInt(i -> list.stream()
                                     .filter(j -> !i.equals(j))
                                     .mapToInt(j -> i + j)
                           )
              .map(Math::abs)
              .min()
              .getAsInt();
```